# Highlight Usages "To remove highlighting of usages" PyCharm button

Tags: pycharm

I am looking at this cool feature in PyCharm

However I don't know what button is this on a mac:

[image]:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/highlighting-usages.html

Answer (score 0):

That is the **`Escape`** Key. You can also view other keymaps (to compare the keys, where relevant) using the dropdown on the top right corner on the page.[image]

I hope this helps!